# Neo4j-OGM relations not being loaded

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In my project I have **MapNodes**, which are connected by a relation `ConnectRelation`. `ConenctRelation` has a property length. Nodes and their relations are saved to the `Neo4J` database without problems. But when loading the Nodes, the `relationsList` is empty.

---

**MapNode class**

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class MapNode extends Circle implements IObservable{

@GraphId
Long id;

@Relationship(type = "CONNECTS_TO")
private ArrayList<ConnectRelation> relations = new ArrayList<>();

@Property(name="x")
private double xCoordinate;

@Property(name="y")
private double yCoordinate;

public ConnectRelation connectToNode(MapNode otherNode){
    ConnectRelation relation = new ConnectRelation(this,otherNode);
    relation.setLength(2);
    this.relations.add(relation);
    return relation;
}
.
.
```

---

**ConnectRelation class:**

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class ConnectRelation extends Line implements IObserver {

@GraphId
Long id;

@StartNode
MapNode startNode;

@EndNode
MapNode endNode;

@Property(name="startX")
private double startXCoordinate;
@Property(name="startY")
private double startYCoordinate;

@Property(name="endX")
private double endXCoordinate;
@Property(name="endY")
private double endYCoordindate;

@Property(name="length")
private double length;
.
.
```

---

**Fill and load methods:**

```
 public static void fillDb(){
    getSession().purgeDatabase();

    Room roomOne = new Room();
    roomOne.setXCoordinate(100);
    roomOne.setYCoordinate(100);
    Room roomTwo = new Room();
    roomTwo.setXCoordinate(200);
    roomTwo.setYCoordinate(200);

    ConnectRelation connectRelation = roomOne.connectToNode(roomTwo);

    getSession().save(roomOne);
    getSession().save(roomTwo);
    getSession().save(connectRelation);
}

public void loadNodes(){
    mapNodeList = new ArrayList<>(DatabaseRepository.getSession().loadAll(MapNode.class,2));
    mapNodeList.forEach(n -> {
        n.getRelations().forEach(r -> {
            if(!relationList.contains(r)){
                relationList.add(r);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem I have is that the relations field in MapNode is empty when loading the nodes, even when the depth is set to something larger than 1.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only obvious thing I can see is the relationship type not being defined on the `@RelationshipEntity`-

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "CONNECTS_TO")
public class ConnectRelation...
```

That could be it- please add it and if the relationships are still not loaded, could you turn debug on and share anything of interest?
Add

`<logger name="org.neo4j.ogm" level="debug" />`

to logback.xml

Comment: You're right the type definition was missing. Adding it fixed it.
Must have slipped my mind when recreating the project.
Thanks again!